# Adding appsettings.json to the publish folder

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I have a dotnet core console project where it takes some data from appsettings.json. It works when running directly from command promt i.e `dotnet run`. But when built, it says appsettings.json is not found on the folder. How to copy the appsettings.json to the build folder?

Here is my console code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(){
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        BuildConfig(builder);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
            .CreateLogger();

        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddTransient<ICoviSlotTrackerService, CoviSlotTrackerService>();
            })
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build();

        var svc = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<CoviSlotTrackerService>(host.Services);
        svc.Run();
    }

    static void BuildConfig(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true) // adding the json file here
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }

}
```

Here is how the folder structure is

[image]

When I run `dotnet build` and double-click exe, i get this error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the following XML in your `.csproj` file:

```xml
<Content Include="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

This way you're telling the MSBuild process that it should copy the content file.

Comment: Changed Content to None. I can see the appsettings.json. Could you please change your answer, I can mark it as correct. and Thanks a lot for the heads up

Comment: @RanjithVaratharajan It could be either [Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019#content) or [None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019#none) - both support `CopyToOutputDirectory` command. The content is preferable because of the purpose of it. From the docs: *Represents files that are not compiled into the project, but may be embedded or published together with it.*